# Getting Access Denied Error While Running Hadoop-2.3 Mapreduce Jobs in windows 7 without cygwin

Tags: windows, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run hadoop-2.3 mapreduce job in windows 7.

I built hadoop-2.3 in windows 7 without cygwin and started hadoop services are all running perfectly. But if i am trying to run any mapreduce jobs i am getting below error.

I started all services with Admin rights.

Error :

```
Application application_1410483662307_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1410483662307_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: 5 due to: Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: createTask error (5): Access is denied.
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: createTask error (5): Access is denied.
```

But it is wroking in Windows 8 & 8.1.

How to solve this problem any can help me?

Thanks,

Comment: Me too have this problem in hadoop 2.5.0 in windows 7. Searching "createTask error (5): Access is denied." in google only point me to this page. Have you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi kholis, I didn't solved that issues. But now it is working in cmd(run as admin). But using c# code i can't able to run the mapreduce job.

Comment: Hi MarHserus, I think this is Windows 7 issue rather than hadoop. https://www.google.com/search?q=error+5+access+is+denied+windows+7.

I give my user full permission to hadoop dir and now the error message is gone: "icacls C:\hadoop-2.5.0 /grant MYUSER:(OI)(CI)F /T". 

I'm not really sure about it, I will test it for couple of days. Hope it help someone.

Comment: I face the problem again. Set full permission is not solution. Still figure it out.

Comment: Yes, problem occured in "hadoop/logs/userlogs" folder. there is no permissions for this folder in windows. but it worked in windows 8, problem occured in windows 7 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the WinUtils.exe used for the task creation. WinUtils.exe used **AssignProcessToJobObject()** in the **createTask()** method in ***task.c*** file.

In windows 7, If the Jobobject has already a process assigned, then ‘AssignProcessToJobObject’ cannot assign a new process and returns with ‘Access Denied’ message.

[image: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681949(v=vs.85).aspx]
So when you called the exe programatically, the jobObject may be already assigned with a ProcessHandle which then returns as "Access Denied" from the 'AssignProcessToJobObject' function.

**Fix:** Check the JobObject for any associated processes and assign a new process only if the jobObject is not assigned to any. Ensure your changes apply only to the Windows 7 environment and let the default code to be used in the Windows 8 and greater environments.

Hope this helps.